# flex: 1, is not working properly react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, styles

After adding `flex : 1`, screen turning white screen, when I remove the `flex : 1`, it shows

what is the problem, I cant find, please reply sooooooon

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Header } from '../components/home/Header'
import Post from '../components/home/Post'
import Stories from '../components/home/Stories'
import { POSTS } from '../data/posts'
import BottomTabs, { bottomTabIcons } from '../components/home/BottomTabs'

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header />
            <Stories />
            <ScrollView>
                {POSTS.map((post, index) =>(
                <Post post={post} key={index} />
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
           <BottomTabs icons={bottomTabIcons} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1, 
        backgroundColor : 'black',
    }
})

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: You will need to give a minimal-reproducible-example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Try to remove as much as possible from the HomeScreen while keeping the bug.

Comment: please cleanup the question (wrap code and explain the context). Also, what are you giving the flex to? Nothing is using styles.container in your example.